# Solaris 10 - Netra 240 - Trying to get to ok prompt

Tags: solaris

Using system console access to Solaris 10 on a Netra 240 and pressing Ctrl+Pause on my keyboard gives me the following:

SC Alert: SC Request to send Break to host.

No ok prompt appears however, just a blinking cursor.

I'm using Secure CRT as the terminal emulation program.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Is that really all the info you can provide?  Doesn't seem like nearly enough to give a good analysis of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas you can play around with:

1. Is your server entirely headless and the only console access you have is through the serial connection? If not, check the OpenPROM settings and make sure that output-device and input-device are set correctly. See eeprom(1M).
2. Did you enable the alternative break sequence? Instead of sending a break signal over the serial line try "Return Tilde Crtl-B". See kbd(1).
3. Are you able to access the ALOM through the console connection with #.? If so, see if the break command works from the sc prompt.

Those are the three things I'd look into first. Let us know how it works out.